# ERROR Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded with SSR & Dynmaic components

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I apply dynamic components with `_compiler: Compiler & _compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync`

```
 var mod = this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TmpModule);
 var factory = mod.componentFactories.find(function (c) { return c.componentType === FooterTempComponent; });
 container.createComponent(factory);
```

I'm not building with the `AOT` mode.

Can't I use `_complier.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync()` in SSR?

Comment: Did you solve the error? I'm facing the same :(

Comment: No, It's not possible, U can't compile on run-time neither if u use the AOT compiler or with SSR.